# -ksh: pushd: not found

Tags: ksh, pushd

I am trying to used pushd, popd and dirs in SUSE Linux but I am getting

```
-ksh: pushd: not found
```

while I try to check pushd

```
 which pushd
which: no pushd in (/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin)
```

I am getting there is not pushd.

Comment: You probably don't have `pushd`. FWIW, in bash it's a shell built-in. But see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/984635/pushd-popd-on-ksh for suggestions.

Answer (score 6):

`ksh` does not have `pushd`, `popd` as built-in. But it has an [implementation](http://www.kornshell.com/examples/pushpopdirs) for you.

Try:

```
. /usr/share/ksh/functions/pushd
```

or:

```
. /usr/share/ksh/functions/popd
```

Then you can use `pushd` and `popd`.

To make it permanent, you can source those files directly in your `.kshrc` or add them to `FPATH` environment variable.

Comment: Paths containing shell functions you might want to use on a regular basis like this can be added to the value of the `$FPATH` environment variable which gets them sourced and run automatically when called.

Comment: I don't have access to use /ush/share/ksh/ path. I have to implement it.

Comment: @AmritdeepDhungana Check if it’s in `/usr/share/ksh/fun/`?

Comment: FWIW, the next official release of `ksh93` may well have these two functions enabled as external functions by default, judging from what I've seen in the discussions amongst the devs.